# Array of double values in MIPS64 assembly

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, mips

I am trying to translate some C code to MIPS64 assembly. Currently I need to translate the following code, but I am not able to get anything to work. How would you safe it to the .data registers?

```
double b[MAX_TAP] = {
    3.558363, -0.542859, -0.928322, -0.993428, 4.643953, -5.909149, 1.722120, -1.854375,
    -1.967672, -2.170269, 0.673272, 0.182548, -4.812593, 0.818270, 0.889598, 0.322937,
    -0.430576, -4.259421, -0.983597, 4.285341, -2.333795, 1.856496, -4.711222, -0.517585,
    -8.376492, -1.440117, -6.255069, -0.000203, 0.881922, 6.955272, -0.209273, 5.219892 
};
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Now does your incorrect `the .data registers` term refer to CPU registers or the data segment in the executable?

Comment: sorry for the error! I meant the data segment in the executable.

Comment: then use the `.section .data` directive.

Comment: I need to simulate the code with winmips64. This software does not support that directive. I can only use .text .data .code .org .space .ascii .asciiz .align .word .byte .word32 .word16 and .double  I tried .ARRAY_X .double 0.3,45.2,11.2,etc but this does not compile as well

Comment: then use `.data`, respectively. What assembler are you using? GNU toolchain? Proprietary? NASM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write:

```
.data
b:
.double 3.558363, -0.542859, ...
```

Comment: Thanks Antoine! How can I load the "max_tap'th" value into a certain register?